# Unhandled Runtime Error Error: Configuration must contain `projectId`

Tags: javascript, next.js, sanity

I'm getting this error again and again. I've provided `projectID` as well via env file, still getting
I'm new to NextJS and sanity as well, your help will be appreciated.

```js
import sanityClient from '@sanity/client';
import imageUrlBuilder from '@sanity/image-url';

export const client = sanityClient({
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_APP_PROJECT_ID,
  dataset: 'production',
  apiVersion: '2022-03-10',
  useCdn: true,
  token: process.env.NEXT_APP_SANITY_TOKEN
});

const builder = imageUrlBuilder(client);

export const urlFor = (source) => builder.image(source);
```

I'm following a tutorial on NextJS tutorial on youtube. I was expecting it to be run smoothly, but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

So I have the same issue with you. So make sure your enviroment variables starts with VITE in case you are using VITE

In my case , I did with this way

```js
import  SanityClient  from "@sanity/client"
import imageUrlBuilder  from "@sanity/image-url";

// take these from sanity manage

export const client = new SanityClient({
    projectId:import.meta.env.VITE_REACT_APP_SANITY_PROJECT_ID,
    dataset:'production',
    apiVersion:'2023-01-10',
    useCdn:true,
    token:import.meta.env.VITE_REACT_APP_SANITY_TOKEN,
})

const builder =  imageUrlBuilder(client);
export const urlFor = (source : any) => builder.image(source);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

And my `.env` file is like this

```html
VITE_REACT_APP_SANITY_PROJECT_ID = aweqfrstbsrgvsrtbvr 
VITE_REACT_APP_SANITY_TOKEN = skm29cF1q1VsOgKIFty8D53j2dJKly9Fa..........
```

Make sure give a space in env file before and after the `=` sign